# Adding Z (elevation to image when georeferencing with gdal_translate and gdalwarp via gcps)

Tags: raster, georeferencing, elevation, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I have been trying to georeference an image with given gcps (X-Y coordinates and Z (elevation) coordinates). However, when I add gcps via gdal_translate it adds elevation Z but as soon as I use gdalwarp, the elevation disappears and I only get a X-Y referenced image. But I also need elevation in the image. Here is my code and the image that I am using.

```
import gdal
gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 0 0 15329.29997 21690.27067 5412.112601 -gcp 0 724 15330.29997 21690.27067 5412.112601 -gcp 1904 0 15329.29997 21689.27067 5412.112601 -gcp 1904 724  15330.29997 21689.27067 5412.112601 test.tif out-with-gcpXYZ.tif
gdalinfo "out-with-gcpXYZ.tif"
#then
gdalwarp out-with-gcpXYZ.tif test0Z.tif
gdalinfo "test0Z.tif" #it lags the elevation (Z)
```